# Retrieving users location with Parse nearGeoPoint

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, location

I have an user table and every user has own location (PFGeoPoint object). Now what is I want to do is sorting and retrieving users from nearest to farthest location. The problem is some users doesnt have any location info(latitude, longitude, geopoint). Their currentLocation column are empty. That's way query doesn't work as I expected.

I put below code to save users location to parse

```
    [PFGeoPoint geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground:^(PFGeoPoint *geoPoint, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"User is currently at %f, %f", geoPoint.latitude, geoPoint.longitude);
    self.userLocation = geoPoint;
    [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:geoPoint forKey:@"currentLocation"];
    [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];

 }];
```

And put below code on my retrieve query method

```
PFGeoPoint *userGeoPoint = self.userLocation; //pass user location to PFGeoPoint

[query whereKey:@"currentLocation" nearGeoPoint:userGeoPoint]; //retrieve users from nearest to rarest
```

Comment: What is the issue? Is it not returning anything, is it returning inaccurate or incorrect results? Please add an exact description of what is not working to your questions.

Comment: The issu is I have 15 users on (parse) _users table. Some users have geopoint, some do nest have. And I want to first bring users which have geopoint info and sorting them from nearest to farthest. But query doesn't bring the users which doesn't have geopoint info.

Answer (score 1):

I updated manually users geopoint information as latitude 0.0, longitude 0.0 if the user doesn't have geopoint info or doesn't let to app to use location. Then I can retrieve users from nearest to farthest whether if they doesn't have geoopint information. And the code that I used for it in viewDidLoad is below.

```
    CLAuthorizationStatus status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

if(status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized ||
   status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways ||
   status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {

[PFGeoPoint geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground:^(PFGeoPoint *geoPoint, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"User is currently at %f, %f", geoPoint.latitude, geoPoint.longitude);
    self.userLocation = geoPoint;
    [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:geoPoint forKey:@"currentLocation"];
    [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];

 }];
}

else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined ||
         status == kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted ||
         status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {

    PFGeoPoint *geoPoint = [PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:0.0 longitude:0.0];

    [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:geoPoint forKey:@"currentLocation"];
    [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to filter out users who don't have a geopoint.

Try this:

```
PFGeoPoint *userGeoPoint = self.userLocation; //pass user location to PFGeoPoint

[query whereKeyExists:@"currentLocation"]; //This is the key line you are missing
[query whereKey:@"currentLocation" nearGeoPoint:userGeoPoint];
```

Comment: Hello Ryan, thanks for your reply but I need also users doesn't have currentLocation. First I'll retrieve users which have geopoint info and sort them from nearest to farthest, then I'll retrieve other users which doesn't have geopoint info.